# Sequences which is/are Big O ($\frac{1}{n}$) as n tends to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, algorithms, asymptotics

Which of the following Sequences is/are Big O ($\frac{1}{n}$) as n tends to infinity

a) $\frac{(n+1)}{(n^2)}$

b) $\frac{(n+1)}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

c) $\frac{1}{nlog(n)}$

d) $\frac{(e^n)}{(n^5)}$

I can get the answer A but can't seem to figure out how C is also an answer.
Because when we do lim n tends to infinty $\left(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right)$ in case of C option it comes as 0.
And that implies small O.

Comment: For C) just note that $\frac 1  {\log n}$ also tends to $0$.

Comment: Hi! I see you have an answer, but it's still preferable if you can MathJax your expressions. You can use `$\frac{n}{d}$` to get $\frac{n}{d}$, `$a^b$` to get $a^b$, `$\log x$` to get $\log x$, etc.

Comment: Any small o is a big O because if the quotient tends to $0$ then it is bounded.